# Why can't get SOAP 1.2 response from IIS

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I setup a web service using C#, and publish it in IIS 6, and the SOAP 1.2 request and response should be like this:

SOAP1.2 request

```
POST /WebServices/EUWS.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.30.178.81
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://www.eutesttools.com">
      <num1>double</num1>
      <num2>double</num2>
    </Add>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

SOAP1.2 response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <AddResponse xmlns="http://www.eutesttools.com">
      <AddResult>double</AddResult>
    </AddResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

But actually when I post this request:

```
Content-Type    application/soap+xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://www.eutesttools.com">
        <num1>3</num1>
        <num2>5</num2>
    </Add>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Then I always get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <AddResponse xmlns="http://www.eutesttools.com">
        <AddResult>8</AddResult>
    </AddResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Why I cant get the described response?

Answer (score 1):

That *is* the right response. The prefix doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know why the prefix is not same?

Comment: Prefixes are not relevant. They can be anything at all, as long as it is unique within the document. A namespace prefix is nothing more than an alias for the namespace itself. As long as it equates to `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`, it will mean exactly the same thing.